# Method not applicable error using Jsoup in custom Java code

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, talend

I'm having issues using Jsoup in a `tJavaRow` component in Talend.

Here is my Job:

[image: Job Layout]

Through `tLibraryLoad` I load the `.jar` files for Jsoup and the java.io.File library and then import them into the `tJavaRow_2` component:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.File;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

And then try to run the following code in the main part of the `tJavaRow_2`:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_" + context.keywordname +".txt", "utf-8");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_" + context.keywordname +".txt", "utf-8");
        Elements el = document.select(".gutter10");
        Elements el = document.select(".gutter10");
        String result = el.text();
        String result = el.text();


        if(result.length() > 20)
        if(result.length() > 20)
            {context.lastpage = true;};
```

Seems logical to me so far.
But I get this error:

[image: Talend Error]

Can you help me resolve this problem? I don't understand what to do from this point on.

**APPENDIX**: Java Code that works in Eclipse:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.File;
//import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class regextest  {

    public static boolean regExChecker() throws IOException 
    {
        boolean x = false;
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/absolventa_testquery.txt"), "utf-8");
        Elements el = document.select(".gutter10");
        String result = el.text();

        if(result.length() > 20)
            {x = true;};

        //System.out.println(x);
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println(regExChecker()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think you can use class and main(String[] args) inside tjavarow code...why do you need these..can you remove these and try

Comment: Hi there! I did this. What you are referring to is just the appendix (the code i use in eclipse). If you scroll a bit up you see the part which I use in tJavarow

Comment: I've tidied up this question so it only asks a single question and with a lot more focus. In general you should try and restrict your questions to just a single point, especially as the two questions you were originally asking were very separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket in your code block. Your first line should be:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_" + context.keywordname +".txt"), "utf-8");
```

As it is, you're building a file from the path `"C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_" + context.keywordname +".txt"), "utf-8"` and then just pass that file object (it won't be a proper file object but for some reason the compiler hasn't spotted this) to the parse method of Jsoup.

Looking at [Jsoup's documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html) the only method call to parse that is a single value is when you pass a HTML document in a string to it. So it is expecting a string and instead gets a (broken) file.

The second error is the one that really points this out by saying you're missing a closing bracket for the VariableInitializer.

Comment: Now it runs smootly, but doesn't stop when the value turns True.
Do i have to mark them as global values or is context.lastpage (boolean) okay as loop end criteria?

Comment: That's probably another question on it's own. As mentioned in my previous answer I'm not too sure when the tLoop will check for variables being set later on in the processing. I think I might have something from a job I created a while back that basically waits for a file and then checks to see if the file size increased (meaning that the file hasn't finished transferring) using a tLoop.

Comment: I might post another question regarding this, to mark the part problem solved